# "Why" followed by gerund

Tags: gerunds

> **Why** noting them down must be a comfort to you.

This construction is a little odd to translate into my native language. 'Why' as a beginning word is normally used in interrogative sentences, but it is followed by a gerund. What is another simple construction of this sentence conveying the same sense?

Comment: Can you give us some more context as it seems hard to understand it as a stand-alone sentence?

Comment: This isn't a sentence. Although the context is listed in an answer, no wonder you are having a hard time. The author you're reading doesn't follow basic punctuation or grammar rules himself. Don't waste your time trying to understand that stuff - go read something better.

Answer (score 1):

I think a punctuation mark is left out.

> Why, noting them down must be a comfort to you.
>
> Why! Noting them down must be a comfort to you.

[It's an exclamation (7)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/why) used at the beginning of a sentence to display an emotion (usually, surprise or anger).

The author doesn't seem to follow some punctuation rules.

> "And it is not only me--I should say I," I continued; "I don't want you to run away with the idea that I am the only good man in the world. That's what I like about Christmas, it makes everybody good. The lovely sentiments we go about repeating! the noble deeds we do! from a little before Christmas up to, say, the end of January! why noting them down must be a comfort to you."

Answer (score 1):

The interogative pronouns "what" "how" "why" etc can form content clauses meaning "the thing that...", "the method that..." and "the reason that..."

So the apparent meaning is

> (The reason that you are noting them down)  (is assumed to be) (a comfort to you).

However this is junk. It is very unlikely that a reason for noting something down could be a comfort.

But I can use the same construction in a reasonable sentence:

> I will tell you why noting down the speaker's comments can help you in a debate.

Which means "I will tell you the reason for you to note them down."